# Command Substitution does not execute unless i echo it

Tags: bash, shell

I have a method that curls, formats the output and returns it as an array.

```
function hdfs_ls_curl() {
  ls_url=$1
  ls_result=$(curl -s --negotiate -u : ${ls_url})

  #gets the foldernames from the json returned. works fine.
  folder_names=$(echo $ls_result | grep -oP '(?<="pathSuffix":").+?(?=")') 

  #echo $folder_names  <--- MAGIC ECHO

  folder_array=( $folder_names )
  return $folder_array
}
```

If i execute without the echo, nothing is returned. Adding the echo lets it behave properly.

Is the command substitution not happening without an actual execution statement?

Comment: There isn't enough here to tell for sure, but it sounds like you're confusing the function's *exit status* (a small number indicating success (zero) or failure (nonzero)) with its *output* (what it prints during its execution). `return` controls the *exit status*; `echo` produces *output*. `$( )` captures *output*, not exit status.

Comment: @SutirthaDas : Your `return` statement does not make sense. Look at the bash man page: `return` expectes a small integer number, and this sets the exit code of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [GordonDavisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) pointed out, removing the return statement and just printing it as an array did the job.

The function will return the printed value and i can parse that in the main program.

Comment: You don't need to print anything either. Just run the function **without** any command substitution, and variables it sets will remain set after it exits.

Comment: Could you show us the returned JSON, so we could write a canonically correct answer using `jq`? (Trying to parse JSON with regexes is going to go badly when you encounter an unusual name -- like one that contains literal quotes, or tabs, or other characters that require their own spacing to be present inside JSON data).

Answer (score -2):

```
> folder_names=$(echo $ls_result | grep -oP '(?<="pathSuffix":").+?(?=")') 

> #echo $folder_names  <--- MAGIC ECHO

folder_names="echo $ls_result | grep -oP \'\(?<=\"pathSuffix\":\"\).+?\(?=\"\)\'"
eval $folder_names
```

That might work, but watch those escapes.  This saves the actual command itself in the variable, rather than its' output.

Comment: No, no, no! Between the use of `eval` and lack of proper quoting, this code is a disaster waiting to happen. Don't store commands in variables; variables are for data, not executable code. Don't use `eval` unless you fully understand shell parsing (and if you think you need `eval`, that's usually a sign that you don't fully understand shell parsing).

Comment: `eval`ing a string that has had `echo $ls_result` in it is extra dangerous. If you had a file named `$(rm -rf ~)` in the listing, goodbye home directory.

Comment: I admit that I did not think of that.